# String.replace method in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, string, methods, replace

I came across this example in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on using the replace method on strings.

This is the example cited there

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "John Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
print(newstr);//Smith,John
```

I changed the regex to the following and tested it.

```
var re = /(\w?)(\w+)/;
var str = "John Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1, $1");
newstr;//J, ohn Smith
var newstr1=str.replace(re,"$2, $1");
newstr1;//ohn, J Smith.
```

$1 must be `J` and $2 must be `ohn Smith` in this example.
when I reversed the order of $n for newstr1,it should be 'ohn Smith, J`. but it is not.

is my understanding of $1 and $2 (substring matches correct) and why newstr1 is different?

Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `$1` is `"J"`, `$2` is `"ohn"` and the `" Smith"` is unmatched.

```
var re = /(\w?)(\w+)/,
    str = "John Smith";

str.replace(re, function (match, $1, $2) {
    console.log('match', match);
    console.log('$1', $1);
    console.log('$2', $2);
    return ''; // leave only unmatched
});
/* match John
   $1 J
   $2 ohn
   " Smith"
*/
```

Therefore, your swap is switching around the `J` with the `ohn`, giving you `newstr1`.

**Why is this happening?** because `\w` matches a *word*, but `?` makes it optional, so just like `(.*?)(.)` captures one letter in `$1`, `(\w?)` is doing the same. The second capture, `(\w+)` can then only extend to the end of the word, dispite the `+`, because `\w` doesn't match whitespace `\s`.